# RxJava Mockito when - Returning a Resolved Observable

Tags: unit-testing, junit, mockito, rx-java, powermockito

I am testing a method which calls a helper library method that returns an `Observable<Void>` and upon completion it runs it's logic in a `flatMap` and calls an API end point which returns an `Observable<SomeObject>`.

The problem I'm having is that in my test is never getting to the flatMap.

```
@Mock private RequestHelperSourceImpl requestHelper;
@Mock private OrdersRepositoryImpl repository;

// setup & teardown code…

@Test
public void shouldSingleOrder() {
    SingleOrder singleOrder = mock(SingleOrder.class);
    TestSubscriber<SingleOrder> testSubscriber = new TestSubscriber<>();

    when(requestHelper.doJwtRequest(anyString())).thenReturn(Observable.just(null));
    when(repository.getOrder(anyLong(), anyString(), anyString(), anyInt())).thenReturn(Observable.just(singleOrder));

    // The method I'm testing
    spySubject.getOrder(anyInt(), anyString());

    testSubscriber.assertValue(singleOrder);
}
```

Here is the code for the method I'm testing

```
@Override
public Observable<SingleOrder> getOrder(long orderId, String jwtToken) {
    return requestHelper.doJwtRequest(jwtToken)
            .flatMap(Void -> {
                ////////<------ It never gets here
                return repository.getOrder(
                        orderId,
                        requestHelper.getAccessToken(),
                        jwtToken,
                        jtApp.isTryoutInt()
                ).compose(JTRxUtils.applySchedulers());
            });
}
```

And here's the signature for `doJwtRequest`

```
Observable<Void> doJwtRequest(String jwt);
```

Here's the error I get when running the test:

```
java.lang.AssertionError: Number of items does not match. Provided: 1  Actual: 0.
Provided values: [singleOrder]
Actual values: []
 (0 completions)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to at least subscribe to the `TestSubscriber`:

```
spySubject
.getOrder(anyInt(), anyString())
.subscribe(testSubscriber);
```

If your code is asynchronous (because you have a scheduler switch), convert to a blocking Observable first.